# MineRL interactor does not work and how to display agent

Tags: python, windows, reinforcement-learning

i wanted to start with minerl and it works with loading Minecraft. But after it has loaded the screen minimize and it display not anymore. It's because I run the script headless, because I am on Windows and cant access xvfb. Is there a alternative?

And my second problem is the interactor. When I run the command from the Documentation I get an error after some time. Here is the end of the output with the error:

```
2022-03-22 07:30:14 Laptop-Oliver minerl.env.malmo.instance.46e654[184] INFO Minecraft process ready
2022-03-22 07:30:14 Laptop-Oliver minerl.env.malmo.instance.46e654[184] WARNING Tried to launch Minecraft on port 31415 but that port was taken, instead Minecraft is using port 10545.
Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-03-22 07:30:14  File "C:\Users\Rollo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Rollo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
     exec(code, run_globals)Laptop-Oliver
   File "C:\Users\Rollo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\minerl\interactor\__main__.py", line 80, in <module>
minerl.env.malmo[184]    run_interactor(ip=opts.ip, port=opts.port)
  File "C:\Users\Rollo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\minerl\interactor\__main__.py", line 56, in run_interactor
    request_interactor(
  File "C:\Users\Rollo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\minerl\interactor\__main__.py", line 23, in request_interactor
    _MultiAgentEnv._TO_MOVE_hello(sock)
  File "C:\Users\Rollo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\minerl\env\_multiagent.py", line 792, in _TO_MOVE_hello
    instance.client_socket_send_message(("<MalmoEnv" + malmo_version + "/>").encode())
AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'client_socket_send_message'
 INFO Logging output of Minecraft to .\logs\mc_22415.log
```

I looked the Errors up in the code on GitHub but i could not find any of them.
If you need more informations please contact me.

Comment: `xvfb` is used to hide screen so if program has option `headless` then I you get the same result.